# Not using a parallel construction where one is recommended by an ESL instructor

Tags: sentence-construction

While the sentences below don't have a parallel construction like *Region A has a rate of X%, Region B has a rate of Y%*, I wonder if my construction can be preferred over a parallel one.

> The regional unemployment rate in St. John’s is 7.8 percent; **in Northern BC it is 9.3 percent**. In St. John’s, workers require 630 hours of insurable work to qualify for EI benefits; **in Northern BC, workers require 560 hours**.

In the first sentence, I replaced "regional unemployment rate" with "it is"; in the second sentence I omitted "of insurable work to qualify for EI benefits".

An ESL instructor disapproved the way I wrote it. They suggested two options.

**Option 1** is the following:

> The regional unemployment rates in St. John’s and Northern BC are 7.8 and 9.3 percent respectively.

For some reason this option sounds like simply stating facts, while I feel my original one *makes an impact* while stating the facts (when I read it in my mind, the comparison seems more dramatic).

**Option 2** is the following:

> In St. John’s the regional unemployment rate is 7 percent, and workers require 630 hours of insurable work to qualify for EI benefits. In Northern BC, the regional unemployment rate is 9 percent, and workers require 560 hours of insurable work to qualify for EI benefits.

This seems a little grayish. My sentence needs to be in the format of "the rate in region A and region B" and "the hours in region A and region B". This is because the conclusion I am going to draw is about those two factors, the regions are not that important.

My question is, do native users disapprove of my original construction?

Comment: Yes, the original construction is not great. In English writing you would not just use a comma there. You would use **and**. The regional unemployment rate in St. John’s is 7.8 % **and** 9.3 % in Northern BC. [Workers] require [y] in the first and [y+1] in the second to qualify etc.

Comment: Sorry, I had meant to use a ";" instead of that comma.

Comment: If I use the "and" version, it should look like this, *"The regional unemployment rate in St. John’s is 7.8 percent, and in Northern BC it is 9.3 percent"*, right?

Comment: I redid it. Just use that.

Comment: I agree that using a conjunction would sound better. (And be preferable to the way the instructor rephrased it.) However, I'll also note that there *is* a parallel structure that's used when looking at the overall structure. A in B is C; in D it is E. In A, B requires C; in D, they require E.

Comment: @JasonBassford Is this preferable then, *"The regional unemployment rate in St. John’s is 7.8 percent, and in Northern BC it is 9.3 percent"*? I am asking particularly about the *it is* referring to "the regional unemployment rate".

Comment: @AIQ I don't think there's any confusion about what *it* refers to in any version of the sentence.

Comment: Just in case anyone is looking for something similar, one option is to use "that": *The regional unemployment rate in St. John’s is 7.8 percent, and **that** in Northern BC is 9.3 percent.*